# htaccess RewriteRule set the root to sub folder and auto hide .php/.html

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My root folder to many file and folder, because of I using some tools （php composer, node, gulp, bower...） for a lager project.

Q1. change the root folder?

I don't want my project to be too messy. So I save all files running on FTP into a directory named `/app/`

EG:
/www/app/home.php  =  https://xxxx.com/home.php

I tried this, but if I used it, I can't seem compatible '/ end' or 'without /'of Q2

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app
```

Q2. how to hidden the .php and compatible '/ end' or 'without /'

/www/app/home.php  =  https://xxxx.com/home**/**  or  https://xxxx.com/home

I tried it, but not compatible '/ end' and 'without /' at the som

```
RewriteRule ^food/?$ /app/food.php [L]
```

here the part of the relation code

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/app
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)?$ /app/$1 [L,NC]  
RewriteRule ^food/?$ /app/food.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have following .htaccess in site root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ app/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ app/$0 [L]
```

Then you need to have this code in `app/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, But just a part of work out. It's work for compatible '/ end' and 'without /' at the same time.  But the images,css all not work. EG: I can't use http://domain/css/xxx.css. After your app/.htaccess.  I need use the real path likes http://domain/app/css/xxx.css

Comment: Thanks so much,  But, eg: root path  www.domain/  is 404, I want to link to /app/index.php  or /app/home/, how can I do?